# How do I deliver ressources files like .png .jpg in setuptools which aren't package-data

Tags: python, setuptools

I have some modules in my project, where I use `find_packages` to locate them and install as well related packages like `yaml` files. However what if I have a folder called `ressources` that only serves to contains bunch of images without any python modules, how would I include those?

**My Current setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    packages = find_packages(),
    package_data = {'mymodule.config': ['*.yaml']},
)
```

One dirty way I was thinking of, is to put a `__init__.py` in that images folder to fake a package, but there must be a better way? Manifest.IN files would be an alternative, but it doesn't seem like it works when I do a `pip install .` from my project dir

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html (Use a "MANIFEST.in" file)

Comment: @Torxed does that work using pip as well? I had in my manifest file `global-include *.png *.jpg` but it still skipped those files

Comment: @Torxed Oh thanks, that actually solved it, i was missing `include_package_data` flag!

Comment: You're welcome :)